# Convert child table rows as comma seperated values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a requirement where i wanted the child table rows to be shown as comma seperated string instead of multiple rows.

Parent Table : Employee

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 | Tim |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E18 | Sam |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E19 | Rohan |

Child Table: Trainings

| Id | Name | Employee Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P10 | Java Basics | I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P11 | Angular | I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P12 | DotNet | I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E18 |

Expected Output:

| Id | Name | Trainings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 | Tim | Java Basics, Angular |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E18 | Sam | DotNet |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E19 | Rohan | null |

Query i have used

```
select id as Id, name as Name, (select listagg(tr.name, ',') within group(order by id) from trainings where employee_id = employee.id) as Trainings from employee where employee.id = trainings.employeeId(+)
```

Above is just a sample, but in realcase we have more number of columns and many tables being joined.  I know we can use groupby clause, but in our case, we have more number columns(around 200) and all are dynamic where user can choose from Ui(Ag Grid).

Above query yields data with comma seperated string but i am getting duplicate data as shown below on joins.

May i know where am i going wrong? Is there any way to restrict duplicate values on joins and combine multiple child rows to single row using subqueries?

| Id | Name | Trainings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 | Tim | Java Basics, Angular |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 | Tim | Java Basics, Angular |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E18 | Sam | DotNet |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E19 | Rohan | null |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a correlated subquery, you can use a `GROUP BY` with `LEFT JOIN`

```
select e."Id" as Id
, e."Name" as Name
, listagg(tr."Name", ',') within group(order by tr."Id") trainings
from employee e LEFT JOIN trainings tr
ON e."Id" = tr."Employee Id"
GROUP BY e."Id",e."Name"
```

| ID | NAME | TRAININGS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 | Tim | Java Basics,Angular |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E18 | Sam | DotNet |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E19 | Rohan | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/31a5bLQM)

Or as correlated subquery

```
select e."Id" as Id
, e."Name" as Name
, (SELECT listagg(tr."Name", ',') within group(order by tr."Id") 
  FROM trainings tr WHERE e."Id" = tr."Employee Id")
  trainings
from employee e
```

| ID | NAME | TRAININGS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 | Tim | Java Basics,Angular |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E18 | Sam | DotNet |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E19 | Rohan | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GDc_W5Gi)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have more number of columns in real scenario and all are dynamic columns. So wanted to know if there is any other way without grouping?

Comment: i added the correlated subquery

Comment: Thanks, that works but there is one scenario wrt to filters on child table using correlated subquery.

select e."Id" as Id
, e."Name" as Name
, (SELECT listagg(tr."Name", ',') within group(order by tr."Id") 
  FROM trainings tr WHERE e."Id" = tr."Employee Id" and tr."Id" = 'I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P10')
  trainings
from employee e

This results in null values for other records.

Comment: No your query now demans the the trainsid must be 'I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P10 and only tim has, so you didn't explain what you exactly want as result. bzw, changing the question, is not good, you got your answer ask a new one

Comment: I have created another question regarding filters, and below is the link. Could you please look into it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044681/filters-on-correlated-subquery-returns-null-oracle

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `left join` to join both tables by employee_id then `group by` and `listagg` to get the expected output :

```
select e.Id, max(e.Name) as Name, listagg(t.NAME, ',') within group(order by t.Id) as training
from Employee e
left join Trainings t on t.Employee_Id = e.Id
group by e.Id
order by e.Id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EF9Zev3A)

Comment: I am trying with Oracle 12c and getting the below error
ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"

Comment: I did a change can you check