# Filters on Correlated Subquery returns null oracle

Tags: spring-boot, oracle12c, ag-grid-angular

I have the below query which combines the child table records as comma separated strings. But when i try applying filters to the correlated subquery, values be replaced as null instead of removing the record.

Parent Table : Employee

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 | Tim |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E18 | Sam |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E19 | Rohan |

Child Table: Trainings

| Id | Name | Employee Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P10 | Java Basics | I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P11 | Angular | I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P12 | DotNet | I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E18 |

Below is the query which results in the output as shown below

```
select e."Id" as Id
, e."Name" as Name
, (SELECT listagg(tr."Name", ',') within group(order by tr."Id") 
  FROM trainings tr WHERE e."Id" = tr."Employee Id")
  trainingss
from employee e
```

output:

[image]

As shown in the image, child values are grouped as comma separated string as expected, but i am having issues while filtering the child values.

How to apply filters on child column values with the subqueries used. Say i wanted to display rows with JavaBasics and Angular, and expected should be first row. But in the below output image i could see all the rows being displayed with Null values.

What i tried?

```
select e."Id" as Id
, e."Name" as Name
, (SELECT listagg(tr."Name", ',') within group(order by tr."Id") 
  FROM trainings tr WHERE e."Id" = tr."Employee Id" and tr."Id" = 'I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P10')
  trainingss
from employee e
```

Output:

[image]

**Please note, above example is just a sample of what our requirement is and in our real case scenarios we have more than 150 columns and all are dynamic. Hence we don't want to use GroupBy**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exists for every condition or count the empoyees that have the number of trainings if they are exactly like the number training you search

```
select e."Id" as Id
, e."Name" as Name
, (SELECT listagg(tr."Name", ',') within group(order by tr."Id") 
  FROM trainings tr WHERE e."Id" = tr."Employee Id"
  )
  trainings
from employee e 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trainings tr1 WHERE e."Id" = tr1."Employee Id"
  AND tr1."Id" IN ('I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P10'))
```

| ID | NAME | TRAININGS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 | Tim | Java Basics,Angular |

```
select e."Id" as Id
, e."Name" as Name
, (SELECT listagg(tr."Name", ',') within group(order by tr."Id") 
  FROM trainings tr WHERE e."Id" = tr."Employee Id"
  )
  trainings
from employee e 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trainings tr1 WHERE e."Id" = tr1."Employee Id"
  AND tr1."Id" IN ('I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P11'))
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM trainings tr1 WHERE e."Id" = tr1."Employee Id"
  AND tr1."Id" IN ('I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P10'))
```

| ID | NAME | TRAININGS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 | Tim | Java Basics,Angular |

```
select e."Id" as Id
, e."Name" as Name
, (SELECT listagg(tr."Name", ',') within group(order by tr."Id") 
  FROM trainings tr WHERE e."Id" = tr."Employee Id"
  )
  trainings
from employee e 
WHERE e."Id" IN
  (SELECT "Employee Id" FROM trainings 
  WHERE "Id" IN ('I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P10','I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9P11')
  GROUP BY "Employee Id"
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

| ID | NAME | TRAININGS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I1BF91860BCB711EDBF4EF0FBCBCA9E17 | Tim | Java Basics,Angular |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ss-nGsUv)